# Optimality of EDF

Tags: scheduling, process-scheduling, real-time

For [**Earliest Deadline First**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earliest_deadline_first_scheduling), I have read that if utilization is less or equal to 1, the task set is schedulable under EDF. But does this criteria expresses the optimality for EDF? If not, how can we express optimality of EDF? So if I get asked is EDF optimal, can I get away with the following sentence?

**EDF is able to execute T if and only some other scheduler can execute T.**

Comment: Please edit to explain what EDF is an acronym for.  And give a citation (and link if possible) to where you read the claim.

Comment: @WanderingLogic I thought it would be familiar, but there you go I edited my question.